# Можно ли добавить document.write в alert?

Tags: javascript

Так, чтобы при открытии alert в нем дополнялись строки за определенное время(через setInterval);

Comment: Конечно же ответ - __нет__

Answer (score 3):

Нет, потому что `alert` останавливает выполнение скрипта.